# Adding blank rows to display of result set returned by MySQL query

Tags: mysql, resultset

I am storing hourly results in a MySQL database table which take the form:

```
ResultId,CreatedDateTime,Keyword,Frequency,PositiveResult,NegativeResult 
349,2015-07-17 00:00:00,Homer Simpson,0.0,0.0,0.0
349,2015-07-17 01:00:00,Homer Simpson,3.0,4.0,-2.0
349,2015-07-17 01:00:00,Homer Simpson,1.0,1.0,-1.0
349,2015-07-17 04:00:00,Homer Simpson,1.0,1.0,0.0
349,2015-07-17 05:00:00,Homer Simpson,8.0,3.0,-2.0
349,2015-07-17 05:00:00,Homer Simpson,1.0,0.0,0.0
```

Where there might be several results for a given hour, but none for certain hours.

If I want to produce averages of the hourly results, I can do something like this:

```
SELECT ItemCreatedDateTime AS 'Created on', 
KeywordText AS 'Keyword', ROUND(AVG(KeywordFrequency), 2) AS 'Average frequency', 
ROUND(AVG(PositiveResult), 2) AS 'Average positive result',     
ROUND(AVG(NegativeResult), 2) AS 'Average negative result' 
FROM Results
WHERE ResultsNo = 349 AND CreatedDateTime BETWEEN '2015-07-13 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-19 23:59:00' 
GROUP BY KeywordText, CreatedDateTime
ORDER BY KeywordText, CreatedDateTime
```

However, the results only include the hours where data exists, e.g.:

```
349,2015-07-17 01:00:00,Homer Simpson,2.0,2.5,-1.5    
349,2015-07-17 04:00:00,Homer Simpson,1.0,1.0,0.0
349,2015-07-17 05:00:00,Homer Simpson,4.5,1.5,-1.0
```

But I need to show blanks rows for the missing hours, e.g.

```
349,2015-07-17 01:00:00,Homer Simpson,2.0,2.5,-1.5   
349,2015-07-17 02:00:00,Homer Simpson,0.0,0.0,0.0
349,2015-07-17 03:00:00,Homer Simpson,0.0,0.0,0.0
349,2015-07-17 04:00:00,Homer Simpson,1.0,1.0,0.0
349,2015-07-17 05:00:00,Homer Simpson,4.5,1.5,-1.0
```

Short of inserting blanks into the results before they are presented, I am uncertain of how to proceed: can I use MySQL to include the blank rows at all?

Comment: I suppose one way would be to pre-create a load of blank hour rows in a table and then update the necessary ones when the average frequencies are known.

Comment: Get yourself a calendar table (or generate one on the fly) and use that as the source of datetime data and left join with it. If you search for calendar table you'll find many answers detailing how to create and use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL in general has no knowledge about the data, so you have to add that yourself. In this case you will have to insert the not used hours somehow. This can be done by inserting empty rows, or a bit different by counting the hours and adjusting your average for that.

Counting the hours and adjusting the average:

- Count all hours with data (A)
- Calculate the number of hours in the period (B)
- Calculate the avg as you already did, multiply by A divide by B

Example code to get the hours:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS number_of_records_with_data, 
(TO_SECONDS('2015-07-19 23:59:00')-TO_SECONDS('2015-07-13 00:00:00'))/3600 
  AS number_of_hours_in_interval
FROM Results
WHERE ResultsNo = 349 AND CreatedDateTime 
  BETWEEN '2015-07-13 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-19 23:59:00' 
GROUP BY KeywordText, CreatedDateTime;
```

And just integrate it with the rest of your query.

Comment: Somebody didn't like it....(downvoted). I think this is one of the most efficient ways of handling the "data not in table" syndrome which everybody using SQL runs into once in a while.

Comment: Well, I will try it tomorrow and see.

Comment: First of all, following this suggestion will give the average over the given period, not for each hour from given period - and looking at the data snippets in the question this is what the author wants. Secondly, storing all  possible dates just for the sake of avoiding post-processing will result in storing a lot of unnecessary data in the database. Thirdly, such solution will need to be maintained on regular basis so that the dates for current period are always there.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo: This idea is without storing any empty records... The suggested method (using knowledge the poster has over the data) can be adjusted to fit the posters need.

Comment: "data not in table", if needed by the viewing application, should be generated by the application. Worrying the database engine with placeholder data should be avoided unless absolutely necessary. Though of course, if some other database view or table needs the 'dummy' data, then it might be viable to generated it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use MySQL for that. You'll have to do this with whatever you're using later to process the results. Iterate over the range of hours/dates you're interested in and for those, where MySQL returned some data, us that data. For the rest, just add null/zero values.

**Small update** after some discussions with my stackoverflow colleagues:
Instead of **you can't** I should have wrote **you shouldn't** - as other users have proved there are ways to do this. But I still believe that for different tasks we should use tools that were created having such tasks in mind. And by that I mean that while it's probably possible to tow a car with an F-16, it's still better to just call a tow truck ;) That's what tow trucks are made for.

Comment: This is most certainly possible; just generate an appropriate range of datetime values and join with that.

Comment: And as a result, if the author needs the report for a whole year, he'll end up with 24*365 unnecessary records in the database just for the sake of avoiding postprocessing... Plus, you need to maintain this solution on regular basis and add new dates/hours as time goes bye so that current period is available. Database should be used to process the data it has - and you are trying to handle the presentation of the data with a tool that was not made for this.

Comment: I disagree; Having a proper calendar table (as well as a tally table) can be extremely useful. Why would having an extra table with less than 10k rows be a problem? In my opinion it's far easier to handle this on the database side than in the presentation layer. Probably more efficient too. In any case the assertion that _you can't use MySQL for that_ is simply incorrect.

Comment: Fair enough, I've updated my answer to reflect the fact that it is possible to achieve that with MySQL :)

Answer (score 0):

Although you already have accepted an answer I want to demonstrate how you can generate a datetime series in the query and use that to solve your problem.

This query uses a combination of cross joins together with basic arithmetic and date functions to generate a series of all hours between `2015-07-16 00:00:00 AND 2015-07-18 23:59:00`.

Generating this type of data on the fly isn't the best option though; if you already had a table with the numbers 0-31 then all the union queries would be unnecessary.

See [this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3729/4) to see how it could look using a small number table.

[Sample SQL Fiddle with a demo of the query below](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3729/3)

```
select 
    c.createddate as "Created on", 
    c.Keyword, 
    coalesce(ROUND(AVG(KeywordFrequency), 2),0.0) AS 'Average frequency', 
    coalesce(ROUND(AVG(PositiveResult), 2),0.0) AS 'Average positive result',     
    coalesce(ROUND(AVG(NegativeResult), 2),0.0) AS 'Average negative result' 
from (
  select 
  q.createddate + interval d day + interval t hour as createddate,
  d.KeywordText AS 'Keyword'
  from (
    select distinct h10*10+h1 d from (
      select 0 as h10 
      union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 
    ) d10 cross join (
      select 0 as h1 
      union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 
      union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 
      union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
    ) d1
  ) days cross join (
    select distinct t10*10 + t1 t from (
      select 0 as t10 union all select 1 union all select 2
    ) h10 cross join (
      select 0 as t1 
      union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 
      union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 
      union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
    ) h1
  ) hours
  cross join 
  -- use the following line to set the start date for the series
   (select '2015-07-16 00:00:00' createddate) q
  -- or use the line below to use the dates in the table
  -- (select distinct cast(CreatedDateTime as date) CreatedDate from results) q
  cross join (select distinct KeywordText from results) d
) c
left join results r on r.CreatedDateTime = c.createddate AND ResultsNo = 349 and r.KeywordText = c.Keyword
where c.createddate BETWEEN '2015-07-16 00:00:00' AND '2015-07-18 23:59:00' 
GROUP BY c.createddate, Keyword
ORDER BY c.createddate, Keyword;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an idea to do it for add rows with null values in the last of your MySQL query.

Just run this query (in the limit add any number of empty rows you want), and ignore the last column:

```
SELECT ItemCreatedDateTime AS 'Created on', 
KeywordText AS 'Keyword', 
ROUND(AVG(KeywordFrequency), 2) AS 'Average frequency', 
ROUND(AVG(PositiveResult), 2) AS 'Average positive result',     
ROUND(AVG(NegativeResult), 2) AS 'Average negative result', 
null
FROM Results
WHERE ResultsNo = 349 AND CreatedDateTime BETWEEN '2015-07-13 00:00:00' AND 
'2015-07-19 23:59:00' 
GROUP BY KeywordText, CreatedDateTime
UNION
SELECT * FROM ( 
   SELECT null a, null b, null c, null d, null e, 
   (@cnt := @cnt + 1) f
   FROM (SELECT null FROM Results LIMIT 23) empty1
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Results LIMIT 23) empty2 ON FALSE
   JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) empty3
) empty
ORDER BY KeywordText, CreatedDateTime
```